# All USB connected devices seem to turn off and restart after a few seconds - happens every few hours

Tags: usb, drivers, mouse, connection

I've seen this error happen to a few others so thought I'd see if anyone has solved this type of issue.

I recently built a PC a few days ago, with an i9-13900k and a 4090. motgherboard GIGABYTE Z790 UD. This error just started happening where all my USB devices that are connected with simultaneously turn off, then restart after a few seconds. I have a razer keyboard, mouse, mouse pad, and Logitech headset plugged in.

I had a 2080 with a i9-9900k before this with all the same devices that I used and this issue never happened once till I built my new pc just a few days ago.

I've tried uninstalling all the USB devices, updating the BIOS, redownloading new drivers, disabling the selective suspend settings, turning off "allow the computer to turn off this device" in device manager. Is there anything else I can try? This is rather annoying, as I'm scared to play games. I'm on windows 11 too.

tldr; All USB connected devices seem to turn off and after a few seconds turn back on together

**Update**

It happened again, here's some errors I noticed within the last hour in the hub.

I dunno if its related to what happened "Windows cannot store Bluetooth authentication codes (link keys) on the local adapter. Bluetooth keyboards might not work in the system BIOS during startup." source BTHUSB - this was only under the information tab. Got an application error at same time:

Faulting application name: GCC.exe, version: 23.6.27.1, time stamp: 0x92776160 Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.22621.1928, time stamp: 0x7dd9e350 Exception code: 0xc0000374 Fault offset: 0x000000000010c1f9 Faulting process id: 0x0x1FC4 Faulting application start time: 0x0x1D9BC812539DE0A Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\GIGABYTE\Control Center\GCC.exe Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll Report Id: 0b05a2ee-a787-4632-adcd-0abe92cd1b10 Faulting package full name: Faulting package-relative application ID: "

Got this also. "The local adapter does not support an important Low Energy controller state to support peripheral mode. The minimum required supported state mask is 0x2491f7fffff, got 0xffffffff. Low Energy peripheral role functionality will not be available."

Here's another "Error setting traits on Provider {8444a4fb-d8d3-4f38-84f8-89960a1ef12f}. Error: 0xC0000001"

Went and reinstalled gcg and updated the wifi/BT drivers to see if that'll fix it. Dunno why this is happening.

Comment: perhaps a power issue?

Comment: That almost sounds like a voltage issue and the motherboard or OS resetting the USB ports because of over-voltage/over-current - have you verified you're not exceeding the wattage each port can output individually and combined, or exceeding the total voltage/amperage for the circuit on the PSU? Ohms Law: V[oltage] x A[mperage] = W[attage] || `V*A=W`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I'll double check. My current PSU is the Inwin 1250 Watts which seems like it could also handle enough, but I'm not sure. I've read other posts where people said one faulty USB device can cause all of them to disconnet. But I'm not sure if it's that or as you said too much going into the PC.